# docker-compose: send only some traffic through another container (vpn)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vpn

I have an app that consists of a crawler and a MySQL db. I want to go through a VPN when I do my crawler, but then not use the VPN when I connect to my DB. I've managed to get my app container to send all traffic through my VPN container, but now I can't connect to my DB that is located at localhost. I've tried using host addresses `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, and the db's container name but none of them work.

How can I route *some* traffic through my VPN container, and some traffic just normally?

Here is my docker compose file:

```
version: '3.7' 
services: 
    db:
        image: mysql:8
        restart: always
        environment: 
            MYSQL_DATABASE: my_db
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pw
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: pw
            MYSQL_PORT: 3308
        ports:
            - "3308:3306"
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    vpn:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: Dockerfile-openvpn-dev
        restart: always
        cap_add:
            - NET_ADMIN
        devices: 
            - /dev/net/tun
        volumes:
            - ./openvpn:/vpn
        command: openvpn --config /vpn/config.ovpn --auth-user-pass /vpn/client.pwd --auth-nocache
    app:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: Dockerfile-crawler-dev
        environment: 
            MYSQL_DATABASE: my_db
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pw
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: pw
            MYSQL_HOST: db
            MYSQL_PORT: 3306
        network_mode: service:vpn
```

Comment: Please tell me if you still have problems setting this up. Otherwise, could you please accept my answer? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to put *db* and *vpn* on the same network. Local container traffic isn't routed through the vpn. If you don't want to route external traffic through the vpn, you would have to use iptables on the vpn service.
Also make sure to include `redirect-gateway def1` in your ovpn config.

```
version: '3.7' 
services: 
  db:
    image: mysql:8
    restart: always
    networks:
      - default
    environment: 
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_db
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pw
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pw
      MYSQL_PORT: 3308
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
  vpn:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-openvpn-dev
    restart: always
    networks:
      - default
    #might be necessary:
    #links:
    #  - db
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    devices: 
      - /dev/net/tun
    volumes:
      - ./openvpn:/vpn
    command: openvpn --config /vpn/config.ovpn --auth-user-pass /vpn/client.pwd --auth-nocache
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-crawler-dev
    environment: 
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_db
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pw
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pw
      MYSQL_HOST: db
      MYSQL_PORT: 3306
    network_mode: service:vpn
    depends_on:
      - vpn

networks:
  default:
```

Comment: Does this work for anyone? With docker-compose version 1.27.4, I can `ping` through the vpn tunnel from both the `vpn` and the `app` container. But I **cannot** `ping db` from the `app` container: **ping: bad address 'db'**. I have tried this with `links: - db` and without.